# monitor network status for systemd script

Tags: networking, systemd

I am writing service script under systemd which logs bandwidth usage every 1 hour. If network goes down, *something* should tell this script that network is down and the script will stop temporarily. Similarly, if network is up again, *it* should tell it that network is up.

I am using bash to write script on Ubuntu 15.10

Please before you suggest a solution, please note I dont need a work around for this, like:

- pinging some server
- running command every some time